# NextJS 14, set cookie and redirect not working

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to handle a basic prompt for password and login type application.  I would like to set a cookie, then redirect the client to a new URL.

I am able to set the cookie, but I'm not able to get a redirect to work in any condition.

The form's submit function is below:

```js
// /app/page.tsx
    async function onSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        event.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget)

        const response = await fetch('/api/auth', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        setSuccess(response.status);
    }
```

The following is the route handler for `/app/api/auth`. I am able to set a cookie in the two cases where I try it, but I am not able to execute a redirect at all.

```js
// /app/api/auth/route.ts
export const runtime = 'edge';

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const data = await request.formData();

    if (data.get('credential') !== "supersecretpass") {
        // This handles a bad password.
        return new Response(JSON.stringify("Bye"), {
            status: 401,
            statusText: "Incorrect Credentials",
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }

    // This doesn't redirect, but should
    // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect
    console.log("do a redirect")
    redirect("/admin")

    // This doesn't handle a redirect, just sends a 200 repsonse to the client. Cookie gets set.
    // const myResponse = new NextResponse(JSON.stringify("hi"), {
    //     status: 200,
    //     statusText: "OK",
    //     headers: {
    //         'content-type': 'application/json'
    //     }
    // });
    // myResponse.cookies.set("authenticated", "true")
    // return myResponse


    // From https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48434#discussioncomment-6336966
    // NextJS 13.
    // Redirect doesn't work, but cookie gets set.
    // const response = NextResponse.redirect(
    //     new URL("/admin", request.url),
    //     { status: 307 }
    // );
    // response.cookies.set("authenticated", "true")
    // return response;
}
```

A minimal example, using the same code here, can be found at https://github.com/timatlee/nextjs_redirect_testing.

Comment: your code execution might fall into `if (data.get('credential') !== "supersecretpass") ` so you are returning early

Comment: I can see "do a redirect" in the console when I use the correct password, suggesting that I'm not returning in that condition